# Return MAX values (Top 1 and 2) from list

Tags: google-sheets, max, vlookup

I have a Google sheet with data of different players attacks and their corresponding damage.

**Sheet1**

```
| Player   | Attack  | Damage |
|:---------|:-------:|-------:|
| Iron Man | Melee   | 50     |
| Iron Man | Missile | 2500   |
| Iron Man | Unibeam | 100    |
| Iron Man | Dash    | 125    |
| Superman | Melee   | 9000   |
| Superman | Breath  | 200    |
| Superman | X-ray   | 0      |
| Superman | Laser   | 1500   |
| Hulk     | Smash   | 500    |
| Hulk     | Throw   | 500    |
| Hulk     | Stomp   | 500    |
| Hulk     | Jump    | 325    |
```

In my second sheet, I want to list each player and display their *two* best attacks and the corresponding damage. Like this:

**Sheet2**

```
| Player   | #   | Attack  | Damage | Comment   |
|:---------|:---:|:-------:|-------:|----------:|
| Iron Man | 1   | Missile | 2500   |           |
| Iron Man | 2   | Dash    | 125    |           |
| Superman | 1   | Melee   | 9000   | Very nice |
| Superman | 2   | Laser   | 1500   |           |
| Hulk     | 1   | Smash   | 500    |           |
| Hulk     | 2   | Stomp   | 500    |           |
```

*Update:*
Some attack may have been producing the exact same damage, if this happens - I just want to return the first one in alphabetical order.

I am now using the following formulas:
Damage-column: `=MAX(FILTER(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A=A2))`
Attack-column: `=JOIN(",",FILTER(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=A2,Sheet1!C:C=C2))`

This returns the *best* attack/damage. For example on row 1/2:

```
| Player   | #   | Attack  | Damage | Comment   |
| Iron Man | 1   | Missile | 2500   |           |
| Iron Man | 2   | Missile | 2500   |           |
```

But not the *second best*. How do I modify the formula on the second row to return the *second best* attack/damage?

*Update:*
Using `=LARGE(Sheet1!C:C;B3)` in the second row I can get the second best attack from Sheet1, but it dosen't segment on player.

*Update 2:*
`=ArrayFormula(LARGE(IF(Player="Iron Man",Damage),B2))` (using named ranges) returns both first and second best damage. Still trying to figure out how to return the attack-name.

Answer (score 2):

With the data you provided I was able to produce the expected outcome by using this formula:

```
=query({ArrayFormula(iferror(SORT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A),SORT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A),Sheet1!A2:A,1),1)-MATCH(Sheet1!A2:A,SORT(Sheet1!A2:A),0))) , sort(A2:C, 1, 0, 3, 0)}, "Select Col2, Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col1 < 3 ")
```

See if you can get this to work on your data.

[image: Illustration]

[Sample link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qu1lxIQ3S8T7DUTkfIQ7o6E0TudBTtYaSFRmCCEu2MU/edit#gid=0)

EDIT: Based on the comments below, here's an updated version.

```
=query({ArrayFormula(iferror(SORT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A),SORT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A),Sheet1!A2:A,1),1)-MATCH(Sheet1!A2:A,SORT(Sheet1!A2:A),0))) , Sheet1!A2:C}, "Select Col2, Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col1 < 3 order by Col2")
```

Comment: Thanks - this *do* work, but I also need to be able to comment in the J column and sort the rows. Query maybe does not support this?

Comment: Nice! I get a strange result when I paste the formula in the 2-d row. Works OK if change the formula to `=query({ArrayFormula(iferror(SORT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:B),SORT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A),Sheet1!A2:A,1),1)-MATCH(Sheet1!A2:A,SORT(Sheet1!A2:A),0))) , sort(Sheet1!A2:C, 1, 1, 3, 0)}, "Select Col2, Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col1 < 3")`. BRW, it's also shorter.

Comment: Also, the answer is good for finding any number of TOP N values by a group. Found an error, it gives incorrect # if some name has fewer values than 2.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov: See if the updated version solves the error?

Comment: Thank you! I suggest this formula: `=QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({ArrayFormula(iferror(SORT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A),SORT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A),Sheet1!A2:A,1),1)-MATCH(Sheet1!A2:A,SORT(Sheet1!A2:A),0))) , Sheet1!A2:C},COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A),4),"Select Col2, Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col1 <= 2 order by Col2")` . It 1: Uses `array_constrain` to show the result on screen, 2. uses `Col1 <= 2` to say how much top N you need.

Comment: The final formula has an error: when Superman has 2 same values on a metrics =( Melee = 9000, Laser = 9000, it will skip one/

Comment: That's why I sorted the range in the array in the first place (I guess). I doesn't seem te skip one if you use =query({ArrayFormula(iferror(SORT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A),SORT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A),Sheet1!A2:A,1),1)-MATCH(Sheet1!A2:A,SORT(Sheet1!A2:A),0))) , sort(A2:C, 1, 0, 3, 0)}, "Select Col2, Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col1 < 3 ")

Comment: I added a sample link.

Answer (score 1):

I used two different formulas:

1. To get the maximum damage per Player `=FILTER(FILTER($D$3:$D$10,$B$3:$B$10 = $F3), FILTER($D$3:$D$10,$B$3:$B$10 = $F3) = LARGE(FILTER(D3:D10,B3:B10 = $F3),$G3))`
2. To get the attack `=INDEX($C$3:$C$10, MATCH($F3&$I3,$B$3:$B$10&$D$3:$D$10, 0))`

[image]

Comment: Maximum damage per player work almost perfectly, but I realised some attacks may be the exact same damage (see updated question) - getting `#REF` error. 

For attack, I am getting `#N/A` error with the comment _"Unable to find the value Iron Man125 with match"_

Comment: If you need an additional question answered, please post the new question and close this question with an answer selected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give JPV credit but use this for getting the answer on another sheet:

=query({ArrayFormula(iferror(SORT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:B),SORT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A),Sheet1!A2:A,1),1)-MATCH(Sheet1!A2:A,SORT(Sheet1!A2:A),0)-ROW()+1)) , sort(Sheet1!A2:C, 1, 1, 3, 0)}, "Select Col2, Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col1 < 3")

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this formula:

`=QUERY({Sheet1!$A$2:$C},
"select Col2, Col3 where Col1 = '"&A2&"' order by Col3 desc limit 1 offset "&B2-1)`

[image]

It sorts the data by Col3 - metric, and limits the result to 1 row, and offsets the result, so you have top 1, 2, and so on values. In my sample, Superman has 2 same values: 9000, the formula enters "Melee" first because it was at first position in the table, but you may sort it in a query text to get an alphabetical order